# How to put a table and a text inside a div?

Tags: html, css

The code below renders to this:

[image]

but I want this:

[image]

If I remove `<div>hello world</div>` the table fit inside the outside div very well.
But I should add the text to the div and hope the text with the table fit well inside the outside div. Can anybody give me any suggestions?

```html
<div style="background-color:green;border:1px solid red;width:81px;height:60px;">
  <div>hello world</div>
  <div style="height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:red;opacity:0.4;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the initial div with "Hello World" meant to be a static header above the table?

Comment: Remove the 100% from the table div and add the 100% to the table.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `overflow:hidden` to the wrapper element

```html
<div style="background-color:green;border:1px solid red;width:81px;height:60px;overflow:hidden">
  <div>hello world</div>
  <div style="height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:red;opacity:0.4;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `overflow: hidden` should truncate a row and I can't scroll to show the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial answer**

You need to add `overflow: scroll` on the outermost `<div>`. As this is the one that you gave a fixed height.

```html
<div style="background-color:green;border:1px solid red;width:81px;height:60px;overflow:scroll">
  <div>hello world</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;opacity:0.4;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Additional answers**

*Using calc()*

Instead of giving the `.inner` a fixed height of `50px` I've opted to calculate the height using `calc(100% - 1em)`. It takes the height of the `.outer` `<div>` and subtracts the height of a single line of text. This makes it slightly more maintainable than the `50px` version as changing the height of the entire component will now need updating one instead of two numbers.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 81px;
  height: 60px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>hello world</div>
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Using `position: absolute`*

Another option would be to give the `.outer` `<div>` a `padding-top` and to position the `.header` on top of the `padding-top`.

First give your `.outer` a `position: relative` to allow the `.header`'s `position: absolute` to refer to the `.outer` `<div>`. Add `padding-top: 1em` and `box-sizing: border-box` as you want the height of the `.outer` to be based on both the content and the padding.

Next add `position: absolute` and `top: 0` to the `.header` to position it.

The `.inner` gets `height: 100%` and a `overflow: scroll` to let it take up the height of the content of the `.outer` `<div>`.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 1em;  
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 81px;
  height: 60px;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="header">hello world</div>
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I only want the table to scroll not the whole outermost div.

Comment: Good point! I already figured that, three options imho adding a fixed height to the inner `<div>`, using `calc()` or using `position: absolute` on the header and `padding`/`margin` on the inner `<div>`. As @debasish-pothal already did the first, I'll try my hand at the latter two.

Answer (score 0):

1) I have removed the height from 1st div, because it is not necessary there as we are going to scroll the child div

2) in the second div instead of height 100% i have given a height 50px ( you can give any height in px ) as we are going to scroll this div

3) table width 100% will fill the 2nd div

---

```html
<div style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);">
  <div>hello world</div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; background-color: red; opacity: 0.4; height: 50px;">
    <table style=" width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please expalin what you've done, as OP would obviously find this information helpful.

Comment: 1) I have removed the height from 1st div, because it is not necessary there as we are going to scroll the child div
2) in the second div instead of height 100% i have given a height 50px ( you can give any height in px ) as we are going to scroll this div
3) table width 100% will fill the 2nd div